# How to make cone with rounded sides?

Tags: three.js, aframe

Is it possible to make a shape that's in between a cone and a hemisphere?

What I'm imagining is a cone that is progressively less and less pointy until it becomes a hemisphere. That is, the edges (or sides/faces) are not straight across to the top, but instead are curves.

Here's a glitch with the two shapes I have to play around with
https://glitch.com/~cone-and-sphere

Comment: You can set a path and then use it with `THREE.LatheBufferGeometry()` to have an object of whatever shape you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round the corners of a cone using the Loop subdivision algorithm implemented in THREE.SubdivisionModifier.

Here it is in action: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_subdivision.html.